# Linq group by Chunks

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, grouping

I would like to group a list like this:

```
a = { Country = "France", Value = 45, Order = 1 }
b = { Country = "France", Value = 55, Order = 2 }
c = { Country = "Italy", Value = 105, Order = 3 }
d = { Country = "France", Value = 10, Order = 4 }
e = { Country = "Germany", Value = 11, Order = 5 }
f = { Country = "Germany", Value = 852, Order = 6 }
g = { Country = "Italy", Value = 26, Order = 7 }
```

To get the following groups :

```
{ a, b }, { c }, { d }, { e, f }, { g }
```

So in other words grouping by **Country** but following the **Order**.
I don't know how to do that with a Linq statement (and if it is possible)
I think it is not Subgroups because I don't really see a "Master" grouping on top of all.

Comment: Why aren't you grouping a,b,d ?

Comment: Also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-results-by-contiguous-keys

Comment: @jdweng It looks like the groups are intended to be contiguous in the original series.

Comment: https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ#groupadjacent

Comment: @jdweng Because they are not adjacent following the Order